# how to connect to a live server with viewen

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to get my website on a live server with viewen but for some reason, I have the following errors. I am not sure why the errors occurred because I have uploaded all the files to the same public_html folder. The only assistance I had from them was to create a new database, which I did and below is my credentials: I am not sure if my dbh.php is set up correctly:

```
<?php

$dbservername = "localhost";
$dbroot = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbdatabase = "pianocou_loginsystem";

$conn = @mysqli_connect($dbservername, $dbroot, $dbpassword, $dbdatabase);


I got rid of the password just for security reason but did include it in my dbh.. Must I change the dbroot? They also told me to leave it as localhost for the server.

[25-Oct-2018 10:46:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  include_once(header2.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/pianocou/public_html/index.php on line 6
[25-Oct-2018 10:46:32 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
[25-Oct-2018 10:46:32 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() /home/pianocou/public_html/index.php:0
[25-Oct-2018 10:46:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening 'header2.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php70/usr/share/pear') in /home/pianocou/public_html/index.php on line 6
[25-Oct-2018 10:46:32 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
[25-Oct-2018 10:46:32 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() /home/pianocou/public_html/index.php:0
[25-Oct-2018 10:46:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  include_once(viewcounter.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/pianocou/public_html/index.php on line 7
[25-Oct-2018 10:46:32 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
[25-Oct-2018 10:46:32 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() /home/pianocou/public_html/index.php:0
[25-Oct-2018 10:46:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening 'viewcounter.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php70/usr/share/pear') in /home/pianocou/public_html/index.php on line 7
[25-Oct-2018 10:46:32 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
[25-Oct-2018 10:46:32 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() /home/pianocou/public_html/index.php:0
[25-Oct-2018 10:46:32 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: views in /home/pianocou/public_html/index.php on line 118
[25-Oct-2018 10:46:32 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
[25-Oct-2018 10:46:32 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() /home/pianocou/public_html/index.php:0
[25-Oct-2018 10:46:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  include_once(footer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/pianocou/public_html/index.php on line 126
[25-Oct-2018 10:46:32 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
[25-Oct-2018 10:46:32 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() /home/pianocou/public_html/index.php:0
[25-Oct-2018 10:46:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening 'footer.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php70/usr/share/pear') in /home/pianocou/public_html/index.php on line 126
[25-Oct-2018 10:46:32 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
[25-Oct-2018 10:46:32 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() /home/pianocou/public_html/index.php:0
[25-Oct-2018 10:46:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  include_once(includes/dbh.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/pianocou/public_html/index.php on line 127
[25-Oct-2018 10:46:32 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
[25-Oct-2018 10:46:32 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() /home/pianocou/public_html/index.php:0
[25-Oct-2018 10:46:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening 'includes/dbh.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php70/usr/share/pear') in /home/pianocou/public_html/index.php on line 127
[25-Oct-2018 10:46:32 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
[25-Oct-2018 10:46:32 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() /home/pianocou/public_html/index.php:0
[25-Oct-2018 10:46:32 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: conn in /home/pianocou/public_html/index.php on line 131
[25-Oct-2018 10:46:32 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
[25-Oct-2018 10:46:32 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() /home/pianocou/public_html/index.php:0
[25-Oct-2018 10:46:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli_stmt_init() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/pianocou/public_html/index.php on line 131
[25-Oct-2018 10:46:32 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
[25-Oct-2018 10:46:32 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() /home/pianocou/public_html/index.php:0
[25-Oct-2018 10:46:32 UTC] PHP   2. mysqli_stmt_init() /home/pianocou/public_html/index.php:131
[25-Oct-2018 10:46:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli_stmt_prepare() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in /home/pianocou/public_html/index.php on line 133
```

Most of my errors said the same thing....

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gksRr.png)

Comment: change your code from `include_once(viewcounter.php);` to `include_once(__DIR__.'viewcounter.php')'`

Comment: all these warnings are not about mysql :-)

Comment: thanks! will give that a go! so would I need to do that for all my include files? I think it looks like it....

Comment: and the __DIR__ has two underscore on each side?

Comment: Yes! That is magic constant in php

Comment: yes for all calls, you should better give a full path to file.

Comment: maybe that is why my css stylesheet is not working...

Comment: do I need to have a database system?

Comment: I am also not sure why my css is not working... I have the following link tag

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="screen,projection,tv">

Comment: Must I also include the file style.css in include_once?

Comment: For some reason, it can't find my css file

Comment: I have copied my css to the same directory and it should have detected it...

Comment: My website is looking much better after adding include_once(__DIR__... ETC.... Must I do that for all my files? but for some reason, I got an sql error... I guess I also need my database

Comment: but I had tried changing my database $dbroot to my username and $dbpass to my password but still no luck

Comment: My database name is piano0011_loginsystem

Comment: `@mysqli_connect` - the `@` symbol means that you block all error messages. Why? do just `mysqli_connect` and check your errors

Comment: I didn't know that the @ symbol blocks all errors

Comment: but I would like to confirm that for my database.. does root mean username?

Comment: I am also wondering why my navigation bar is not showing in header2.php

Comment: just to confirm... is there a dot after __DIR__?

Comment: I have changed it and uploaded to viewen but not sure what to do...

Answer (score 0):

Database root is not the root it will be your Database user and make sure the Database user has full rights to the Database.

Comment: thanks for the kind assistance but I have selected all the checkbox to give the user full permission and have added the username but don't know why I got sql failed

Comment: I didn't get sql failed in my localhost but just my live server

Comment: did you check if the database user name is correct or you are entering correct password